# Styling input field of dynamic ID using getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some input fields that has its id's number changes dynamically.

For example, the below code shows an input field that has "`id="field14`". The word (*field*) in the id does not change, but the (*number*) is changing dynamically. So it may be field14, field13, or field20, etc, and there is no limit for numbers.

```
<input type="text" name="field[14]" id="field14" value="" size="30" style="height: 24px;">
```

I'm using the following code to style the input field:

```
document.getElementById("field14").style.height = "24px";
```

*Note, the application's PHP code is encoded & I'm editing in smarty template.*

The input code in the template is like this: `{$field.input}` So when I inspect element on the live page it shows the above code of the input  with the dynamic number of the id.

I want a way that allow me to style any input field of the page that **starts** with the word (*field*) and **ends** with a dynamic (*number*). Any suggestions please?

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: You can't add some class name for this specific input with smarty?

Comment: why not add a class for all inputs?

Comment: @JerryB have you tried something amongst the proposed solutions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector:

```css
input[id^=field] {
    /* Styles */
}
```

It will match all `input` elements whose `id` attribute begins with "field". Using some separator between "field" and the number may be better to prevent matching things like "fieldone".

```css
input[id^=field] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="field1" />
<input id="field2" />
<input id="field3" />
<input id="field15" />
<input id="field99" />
```

Comment: If that happens, we shake our fists at the heavens :D

Answer (score 4):

For a pure CSS approach, I would check the `name` instead, so you should only look for input elements whose attribute starts  with `field[` and ends with a closing bracket `]`.

e.g.

```
input[name^="field["][name$="]"] {
   ...
}
```

From the code you posted you can reasonably suppose that the name of all the elements containing a numeric index inside brackets `[]` are also the same elements with that dynamic index as a part of your `id`.

otherwise you may write a more complex set of selectors looking for an `id` starting with `field` and ending with a digit `[0..9]`

e.g.

```
input[id^="field"][id$="0"],
input[id^="field"][id$="1"],
input[id^="field"][id$="2"],
input[id^="field"][id$="3"],
input[id^="field"][id$="4"],
input[id^="field"][id$="5"],
input[id^="field"][id$="6"],
input[id^="field"][id$="7"],
input[id^="field"][id$="8"],
input[id^="field"][id$="9"] {
   ...
}
```

or even combine both the methods

```
input[name^="field["][name$="]"][id$="0"],
input[name^="field["][name$="]"][id$="1"],
...
input[name^="field["][name$="]"][id$="9"] {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i strongly recommand using a class attribute:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="fields" name="field[14]" id="field14" value="" size="30" style="height: 24px;">
```

**CSS**

```
.fields {
  /*style*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want a way that allow me to style any input field of the page that
>   starts with the word (field) and ends with a dynamic (number). Any
>   suggestions please?

This is a *very* specific question that wants us to key on the fact that the id starts with "field" and ends in a dynamic number. IMHO this solution answers your question exactly as asked using only CSS, plus it doesn't require you to change your HTML or add a class attribute (although this would be much better).

This CSS code will find any `<input>` tag that has an id starting with "field" and ending in a number. It will also exclude those that start with "field" but do not end in a number.

```
input[id^='field'][id$='0'],input[id^='field'][id$='1'],input[id^='field'][id$='2'],input[id^='field'][id$='3'],input[id^='field'][id$='4'],input[id^='field'][id$='5'],input[id^='field'][id$='6'],input[id^='field'][id$='7'],input[id^='field'][id$='8'],input[id^='field'][id$='9']
{
    // styling code
}
```

Demo code: http://jsfiddle.net/Drakes/7wpnL/671/

Answer (score 1):

**If you *need* JS approach**:

http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/LEaXxW

```
var num = 2;
document.getElementById("input" + num).style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

If I get you right, you need all your new `input` look somewhat unique or something.

You can think of getting a number of the currently presenting `inputs`, then get the last of them, then attach your style based on what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery:

```
    var inputs = [];
    function getFields(){
        $('input').each(function() {
            if($(this).attr('id').substring(0,5)=='field'){
                inputs.push($(this));
            }
        });
    }
```

you can modify each input inside the "each" loop, or you can use the "inputs" variable.

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsbin.com/kubaku/1/edit?html,js,output

**JS**

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var ID = 'field';
var i;

for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var input = inputs[i];
  var regex = new RegExp("^" + ID);

  if(regex.test(input.id)) {
    input.style.border = '1px solid #c00';
  }

}
```